# A transaction with a decent fee isn't gettingc confirmed

Tags: transactions, bitcoin

I have sent a transaction but it seems like it isnt being confirmed.

I have also added a decent fee.
https://blockchain.info/tx/f18eb6a4a148bae01a1a6da408f6d1a2f190881de0eb0578fcf2447c0b520715

Someone has an idea why it happens?
thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: so? I have seen a lot of questions that arent about programming and they relate to btc

Comment: Please show some examples of those

Comment: It IS about programming. The timing of bitcoins operation is closely tied to the inner, bit  structure of the bitcoins concepts. It is well seen on the answer to this question. ... I am programming bitcoins SW and this subject is important and interesting for me.

Comment: We have a site completely dedicated to [Bitcoin](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com). Please consider asking your Bitcoin questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has been confirmed at this point into block 400468.

For future reference, .0001 btc is not a decent fee anymore, it's just about the minimum. Blocks are currently being filled almost to the max 1MB limit. The size of the previous block, 400467, was 934.408 KB. Every block going deeper alternates between ~750KB and ~950KB. With space becoming more limited in each block, miners would prefer to include transactions that are more profitable.